# OS is swapping when we start ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, swap

We are running ElasticSearch and OS start swapping when we start ElasticSearch.

top - 22:35:42 up 149 days,  2:28,  1 user,  load average: 0.10, 0.10, 0.09
Tasks: 352 total,   1 running, 351 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  65976160 total, 64894808 used,  1081352 free,   196236 buffers
KiB Swap:  8388604 total,  8388572 used,       32 free.  5148992 cached Mem

PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 6149 elastic+  20   0  0.458t 0.032t 219776 S   1.7 51.3   3313:42 java
13253 root      20   0 5918216 326196   7476 S   0.7  0.5 532:41.85 java

Comment: nodes/process : {
  "cluster_name" : "prod_us_v235_nres",
  "nodes" : {
    "2-aYWGCJR7ODvTCx6t9XyQ" : {
      "name" : "usnres08.ebcolo.com",
      "transport_address" : "10.67.22.158:9300",
      "host" : "10.67.22.158",
      "ip" : "10.67.22.158",
      "version" : "2.3.5",
      "build" : "90f439f",
      "http_address" : "10.67.22.158:9200",
      "process" : {
        "refresh_interval_in_millis" : 1000,
        "id" : 6149,
        "mlockall" : true
      }

Comment: It is running fine for all other 4 nodes, only one node is using all the SWAP,

Comment: I find out that it is not ElasticSearch. It is salt-minion. It is taking 8GB SWAP. I like to know how to fix it.

Comment: 1917 root      20   0 31.552g 0.023t   4016 S   0.3 36.8 171:03.13 salt-minion   fgrep Swap /proc/1917/status
VmSwap:  8345096 kB

Comment: No idea how to fix your salt-minion, but in general turn off swap for Elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration-memory.html

Comment: Don't answer if you don't know. I am able to fix it.